# How to create folders for branches in a repository?

Tags: git, repository, organization

How can I create a folder for my branches in my repository to keep the list of branches in origin from getting too long. A folder would at least allow these to become collapsible and can help with group branches by type for features, bugs, release and hotfix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can prefix the branch you want to create with the folder name or branch type you want. For example you can put a feature branch into a feature folder by making the branch name.

> feature/branch_name

This can be done on multiple levels. For example

> feature/home/create_home_page
>
> feature/profile/create_add_profile_page
>
> feature/profile/create_profile_list_page

This is an example of how the tree will look.

> feature/home
>
> ->create_home_page
>
> feature
>
> -> profile
>
> -> -> create_add_profile_page
>
> -> -> create_profile_list_page

Comment: This may not solve the OPs problem since the individual branches will still be listed as individual lines and not as "tree" or "folder structure".

Comment: I am the OP. Wrote this up as I have been searching for a way to create folders for branches using Visual Studios repository for some time all to no avail online but happened to stumbled across it today thanks to a type in the branch name so said I would post in case anyone else needed this solution.

Comment: So your answer is based on a feature of VSC. Then you may make that clear in your (self) answer...

Comment: No not just VSC. I have checked in GitHub and BitBucket and it worked on them as well.